# Java generics, interfaces for multiple objects

Tags: java

I got a task to rewrite application in Java EE and Java JSF. I decided to go with Spring Boot and Angular. Currently I am struggling with generics in Java.

I have abstract class *Item* and few classes which extends this class e.g.:

```
public class Item1 extends Item
public class Item2 extends Item
```

Then I have an abstract class managing these elements (every item has to be treated differently):

```
public abstract class ItemAdapter<ELT extends Item> {

    private final Class<ELT> eltClass;

    public boolean isMyElement(Item item) {
        return eltClass.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass());
    }

    @Transactional
    public abstract void add(ELT item);
}
```

and classes which extends this class:

```
public class Item1Adapter extends ItemAdapter<Item1>
public class Item2Adapter extends ItemAdapter<Item2>
```

When I receive `List<Item> items` I have to perform *add* method based on its type. So I have auxiliary class:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AdapterSetService {
    ...

    public List<ItemAdapter> getAllAdapters() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                item1Adapter,
                item2Adapter,
        );
    }

    public ItemAdapter getAdapterOfType(Item item) {
        for (ItemAdapter adapter : getAllAdapters()) {
            if (adapter.isMyElement(item)) {
                return adapter;
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown type: " + item);
    }
}
```

And what I do is:

```
for (Item item: items) {
    ItemAdapter itemAdapter = adapterSetService.getAdapterOfType(item);
    itemAdapter.add(item);
}
```

The problem is that I get warnings from IDE:

1. In AdapterSetService.getAllAdapters method - "Raw use of parameterized class 'ItemAdapter'"
2. In AdapterSetService.getAdapterOfType method - the same message
3. When calling adapterSetService.getAdapterOfType - the same message

What I was trying to do:

1. Changing AdapterSetService.getAllAdapters and AdapterSetService.getAdapterOfType to retun ItemAdapter<? extends Item> but then I get error when calling itemAdapter.add(item) - Required type: capture of ? extends Item Provided: Item

Any suggetions how to solve this?

Comment: In your for-loop in getAdapterOfType  you return an Object of the abstract class ItemAdapter. I think that counts as raw use.

Comment: `List<ItemAdapter>` — You have defined `ItemAdapter` to accept a type argument (`ELT extends Item`). You haven't given one. This is called 'using *raw types*'. Never use raw types, always provide the type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to safely assume different generic types for elements in a single collection.

I would abandon the generic `add` method and use runtime type checking instead:

```
public final void add(Item item) {
    try {
        addImpl(eltClass.cast(item));
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Expected instance of " + eltClass, e);
    }
}

@Transactional
protected abstract void addImpl(ELT item);
```

Now you can fix all the raw type occurrences of ItemAdapter.  Raw types should never be tolerated in code:

```
public List<ItemAdapter<? extends Item>> getAllAdapters() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            item1Adapter,
            item2Adapter,
    );
}

public ItemAdapter<? extends Item> getAdapterOfType(Item item) {
    for (ItemAdapter<? extends Item> adapter : getAllAdapters()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And:

```
for (Item item: items) {
    ItemAdapter<? extends Item> itemAdapter = adapterSetService.getAdapterOfType(item);
    itemAdapter.add(item);
}
```